# serializeArray внутри each

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let l = $('[id ^= load]'); // находит все айдишники, которые стартуют с load
$.each(l,
     function () {
            console.log(this.serializeArray()); //log: this.serializeArray is not a function 
            console.log(this); //log: <form action="" id="load1" class="load">..</form>
}
    )
```

Сообственно возможно ли перебрать через $.each несколько форм (id = load1, id = load2..) и из каждой формы отдельно получить serializeArray?

Comment: да, это возможно и приведенный код, это и делает

Comment: Да, только он возвращает результат: <form action="" id="load1" class="load">..</form>; <form action="" id="load2" class="load">..</form>, который serializeArray() не берет естественно.

Comment: что логично, чтобы был serializeArray - нужен объект jquery, для получения объекта jquery нужно вызвать функцию `$`: `$(this)`

Comment: Точно, спасибо.